# Unknown error occurred after install on MAMP

Tags: error-message

Successfully installed Craft on MAMP but whenever I load the dashboard, I get the error message "Unknown error occurred". The message clears after a few seconds. The CMS appears to be functioning correctly except when I create a Section, it only allows me to select Single as a type.

Can anyone shed light on this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are your `craft/config` folder isn't [writable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/installing#step-2-set-the-permissions), but you can see the underlying error in your craft/config/storage/runtime/logs files.  Just search for [error] or [warning].

Comment: If the system detects that the `config` folder isn't writable, could _that_ be displayed as the flash message? "Unknown error" is pretty vague.

Comment: Possibly... installation usually catches it, but sometimes that doesn't work if the site developed, then deployed for the first time, for example.

Comment: True... when files get moved from Point A to Point B, often the permissions get screwed up. Just asking because I feel like that mysterious error message has snagged me at some point too. :)

Comment: I had craft/config set as 744. When I set it to 755, the error goes away.